# What't the means about var () in golang

Tags: go, go-swagger

I go though the code generated by go-swagger, found follow code:

```
// NewReceiveLearningLabActsParams creates a new ReceiveLearningLabActsParams object
// with the default values initialized.
func NewReceiveLearningLabActsParams() ReceiveLearningLabActsParams {
    var ()
    return ReceiveLearningLabActsParams{}
}
```

I noticed here:

```
var ()
```

I totally not understand what's the means, could anyone help me understand this code? thanks

Comment: Well, that is an empty var declaration block (autogenerated).

Comment: yes, is only confusing ... if block have more that one argument it could be var (a int, b string), with just one argument "var (a int)", but with zero argument this special case

Comment: Thank all your guys help on this

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In Go this is a shorthand for defining variables in bulk.
Instead of having to write var in front of every variable declaration, you can use a var declaration block.

For example:

```
var (
    a,b,c string = "this ", "is ","it "
    e,f,g int = 1, 2, 3
)
```

is the same as

```
var a,b,c string = "this ", "is ","it "
var d,e,f int = 1, 2, 3
```

The `var ()` in your code example simply states that no variables were declared.

Refer to [the official Go documentation](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#variables) for more information.